# How to update html div content using java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on a java rcp application. Whenever user updates the details in UI, we are suppose to update the same details in html report also. Is there a we can update/add the html elements using java. Using Jsoup I am able to get the required element ID, but not able to innert/update new element to it.

```
Document htmlFile = null;

    try {
        htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:\\ItemDetails1.html"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Element div = htmlFile.getElementById("row2_comment");
    System.out.println("text: " + div.html());
    div.html("<li><b>Comments</b></li><ul><li>Testing for comment</li></ul>");
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 2):

```
Try:

Element div = 
 htmlFile.getElementById("row2_comment");

 div.appendElement("p").attr("class", 
 "beautiful").text("Some New Text")
```

To add a new paragraph with some style and text content

Comment: This updates the div element in the memory, but not on actual html file. When I closed and reopened the file, I do not see any changes.

Comment: To save the file: File input = new File("C:\\ItemDetails1.html");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input,"UTF-8");  then make modfications and :writer.write(htmlFile.html() ) ;
writer.flush(); 
writer.close();